# Kivy: Clearing Text Input with 'on focus' or 'on_touch_down'

Tags: python, kivy

I want to clear a `TextInput`'s `text:` when I click on it.
Sample Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Why does it clear multiple inputs? And why do they get cleared after touch_up?'
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Name'
                on_touch_down:
                    self.text = ''

            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Last Name'
                on_focus:
                    self.text = ''

            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Phone Number'
                on_touch_down:
                    self.text = ''
"""

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Neither `on_touch_down:` or `on_focus` erases JUST the text input that is currently focused. Instead, both get cleared when I touch anywhere on the screen. I would want them cleared individually once the cursor is on a text input. I also tried `on_cursor` but that didn't work either. What am I missing?  **Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Please post a minimal runnable example.

Comment: @inclement, I updated my original inquiry. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_touch_down` event is received by all the widgets until one returns True telling the event-loop that it is using it and thus not send it to other widgets as indicated by the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.on_touch_down):

> **on_touch_down(touch)** Added in 1.0.0
>
> Receive a touch down event.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **touch:** MotionEvent class Touch received.
>
> The touch is in parent coordinates. See relativelayout for a discussion on coordinate
>   systems.
>
> **Returns**:
>
> bool If True, the dispatching of the touch event will stop.
>   If False, the event will continue to be dispatched to the rest of the
>   widget tree.

The classic use of on_touch_down is in python since kv language is limited in the overwriting of methods:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.text = ""
            return True
        return super(MyTextInput, self).on_touch_down(touch)

kv_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Why does it clear multiple inputs? And why do they get cleared after touch_up?'
            MyTextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Name'
            MyTextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Last Name'  
            MyTextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Phone Number'
"""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Or something equivalent in .kv but the devestaja is that you can not return True.

```
kv_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Why does it clear multiple inputs? And why do they get cleared after touch_up?'
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Name'
                on_touch_down: if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): self.text = ""
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Last Name'
                on_touch_down: if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): self.text = ""
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Phone Number'
                on_touch_down: if self.collide_point(*args[1].pos): self.text = ""
"""
```

So you should use on_focus which is an event associated to `FocusBehavior` that overwrites `on_touch_down` verifying using `self.collide_point(*touch.pos)`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Why does it clear multiple inputs? And why do they get cleared after touch_up?'
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Name'
                on_focus: self.text = ""
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Last Name'
                on_focus: self.text = ""
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Phone Number'
                on_focus: self.text = ""
"""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to just add this:

```
on_focus: self.text = '' if args[1] else self.text
```

`on_focus` is a function that gets called when the `TextInput` is selected or unselected, and the function gives you two arguments `instance` which is the thing got selected or unselected and `value` which is if that `instance` got selected or unselected, these two arguments get put in a list called `args`, and since we're doing this in the widget itself in the `kv` file we don't have to worry about `instance`, so we check if the `value` is `True`, and if it is that means that the `TextInput` got clicked, so we clear it, otherwise we set it to itself.

So this is how the script would look like:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Why does it clear multiple inputs? And why do they get cleared after touch_up?'
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Name'
                on_focus: self.text = '' if args[1] else self.text
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Last Name'
                on_focus: self.text = '' if args[1] else self.text
            TextInput:
                text: 'Write Your Phone Number'
                on_focus: self.text = '' if args[1] else self.text
"""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```